# php & ajax returning wrong result

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am a newbie to using Javascript and what I am trying to do is submit a username and password to a php page and then check to see if they exist in the database and if they do load a different page.

At the moment, when I submit the form it returns the value false.  However if I add the values to the php page it returns true.

So I think I must have a problem between the ajax and the php, but i can't see where i am going wrong so any suggestions would be appreciated.

When I run the code in the chrome developer tool, the console displays this warning:

`event.returnValue` is deprecated. Please use the standard `event.preventDefault()` instead.

but i am not sure what it relates to, doing a Google search it seems that this is just a warning, but i am not seeing any other warnings.

HTML form

```
 <label id="errorMessage"></label>
 <form  method="post" class="login">
   <input name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username"/>
   <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
   <input type="submit" name="login" class="login" value="Login" id="orange"/>
 </form>
```

Ajax

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$('form.login').submit(function () {
var username = $(this).find('.username').attr('value');
var password = $(this).find('.password').attr('value');
// ...
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "login.php",
        data: "username="+ username +"& password="+ password,
        success: function(response){
         if(response == 'true')
                {
                     window.location.href='main.html';
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#errorMessage").html(response);
                }   
        }
    });
     return false;
      });
        });
```

PHP

```
   $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
   $password = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));

   if(!empty($username) && !empty($password))
   {
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' and  password ='$password'");
    $num_rows01 = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($num_rows01 === 1)
     {
        echo 'true';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'false';
    }
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried to narrow down your problem? Please test each snippet separately, use Chrome/Firefox debug tools, show reports/read the logs, etc, to find out what snippet is not working properly

Comment: Thanks, I have tried the php code by manually adding the form data and that returned true, so i guess i need to try what you said and check the form and the ajax.  cheers

Comment: Try changing the input type from submit to button...and in jquery .submit to .click ;)

Comment: Thanks, that does nothing actually

Comment: you shouldn't be using Ajax for this, forms are meant to do this exact thing easily and automatedly

Comment: I want to learn how to use ajax with html and php to use in a mobile app and i can not just use a normal html to php fomr to do that.

Comment: So you want to do this in Ajax and are not open to using normal form? If you are trying to learn Ajax, there are tons of good examples/mini-projects to try, but this is not a good one, as Ajax is very redundant here.

Comment: i would try removing the space in the ajax between `&` and `password` when setting the data

Comment: Thanks, i have just discovered it is saying that the username is undefined.  I am looking for some other tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont have any class called `username` and `password`.So it's not retrieveing those values.

Change this:

```
var username = $(this).find('.username').attr('value');
var password = $(this).find('.password').attr('value');
```

To:

```
var username = $("[name='username']").val();
var password = $("[name='password']").val();
```

**Note:** Retrieving password on the client-side is dangerous and your site has high chances of getting hacked.So this approach is highly insecured and suggest you to use the normal form submission